# Why does Python int have a __round__ method?

Tags: python, methods, types

What is the reason that `int` types have a `__round__` method associated with them when rounding up integers doesn't make any sense?

```
>>> int.__round__
<method '__round__' of 'int' objects>
```

Comment: It would be surprising to not be able to round a number, even if it's an integer and it doesn't make a whole lot of sense…!?

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed round integers too (round 8 to 10, for example).
In Python the rounding is only possible if the `__round__` method is available.

Here's a short example to explain it in code:

```
>>> int(round(5678,-1))
5680
>>> int(round(5678,-2))
5700
>>> int(round(5678,-3))
6000
```

You cannot round a string, instead, because it doesn't have the `__round__` method.

Methods with names that have both leading and trailing double underscores are reserved for special use in the language.
This rule covers things like `__init__` for object constructors, or `__call__` to make an object callable, such leading and trailing double underscores names are also called "dunders".

Answer (score 1):

First, this functionality was implemented in Python3 (doesn't exists in Python2).

Python2:

```
>>> int.__round__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'int' has no attribute '__round__'
```

Python3:

```
>>> int.__round__
<method '__round__' of 'int' objects>
```

The "round" method was used to round the number in the length(amount) of the provided second number:

example:

```
>>> int(round(4485,-2))
4500
```

```
>>> int(round(4485,-1))
4480
```

```
>>> int(round(4485,0))
4485
```

Answer (score -1):

As a number, we should be able to round it, and in Python this is only possible when the class of the object has a **round** function with it. A counter-example is `str`.

````
>>> s = 'my_str'

>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>

>>> dir(s)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', ...
# to show there is no __round__ function for str

>>> round(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type str doesn't define __round__ method```
````

It works very much like a `trait` or `interface` in JVM languages.

Comment: The question is why int should have round function